# Mass renaming files issue

Tags: ruby, file, rename

I have files that are named like so:

```
item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352%26rn%3D490896865329d1a07c116d0fa2ccde83&usg=ALkJrhhLjeT_LoGV64BkCnaLGgNbCgWAAA.html`
```

I would like to rename them by splitting the basename on the string `%26rn%` and returning the 0 index so the desired filename would be: `item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352.html`

I put together a rename script like so:

```
puts "Renaming files..."
Dir.glob("localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html/*.html").each {|i|
  File.rename(i, "localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html/#{File.basename(i).split('%26rn%')[0]}.html")
}
puts "Renaming complete."
```

This doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `ll = 'item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352%26rn%3D490896865329d1a07c116d0fa2ccde83&usg=ALkJrhhLjeT_LoGV64BkCnaLGgNbCgWAAA.html'`
`ll.split('%26rn%').first` => `"item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352"`

Comment: This doesn't solve the renaming issue, thanks for your input though.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `This doesn't seem to work`?

Comment: The issue is that the files aren't renamed. I changed the split in my code from the 0 index to .first like you supplied but the rename still doesn't happen.

Comment: I have tried code similar to yours and it worked as expected. Have you tried adding some basic print statements to see what the resulting renamed files are?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your version because I tried some puts statements to print the filename's and renamed values and those don't work either. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this (untested) code:

```
BASE_PATH = 'localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html'

puts "Renaming files..."

Dir.glob(File.join(BASE_PATH, '*.html')).each do |old_filename|
  new_filename = File.join(
    BASE_PATH,
    File.basename(old_filename)[/^(.+?)%26rn%/, 1] + '.html'
  )
  File.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

That's not guaranteed to work, but it looks correct.

Don't use single-letter variables, except for short loops where you're counting; Traditionally we'd use `i`, `j`, `k`, etc. in that case. For your use, use something more indicative of what your variable is, `old_filename` tells us a lot more than `i`.

Also, don't `split` the string, do what you intend and grab the first part of the string up to your `%26rn%` marker:

```
foo = 'item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352%26rn%3D490896865329d1a07c116d0fa2ccde83&usg=ALkJrhhLjeT_LoGV64BkCnaLGgNbCgWAAA.html'
foo[/^(.+?)%26rn%/, 1] # => "item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352"
```

From that you can see what happens here:

```
BASE_PATH = 'localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html'

old_filename = 'item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352%26rn%3D490896865329d1a07c116d0fa2ccde83&usg=ALkJrhhLjeT_LoGV64BkCnaLGgNbCgWAAA.html'
old_filename[/^(.+?)%26rn%/, 1] # => "item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352"

new_filename = File.join(
  BASE_PATH,
  File.basename(old_filename)[/^(.+?)%26rn%/, 1] + '.html'
)
new_filename # => "localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html/item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352.html"
```

Note: [`File.join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-join) is aware of the proper path delimiter to use for *nix vs. Windows, and Ruby will [use backslashes or forward-slashes as appropriate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html). It'd be more correct to write:

```
BASE_PATH = File.join( %w[ localhost Users Admin Desktop html ] )
# => "localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html"
```

if you want cross-platform compatibility, but for the purpose of the example I used the `'localhost/Users/Admin/Desktop/html'` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good with RegEx so I will do as below :

```
file ='item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352%26rn%3D490896865329d1a07c116d0fa2ccde83&usg=ALkJrhhLjeT_LoGV64BkCnaLGgNbCgWAAA.html'
base_name = File.basename(file)
ext_name = File.extname(file)
new_name = base_name[0..base_name.index('%26rn%')-1] + ext_name
# => "item.htm%3Fid%3D26184136352.html"
File.rename(file,new_name)
```

Comment: what about the complete modified script including the each; because I tried to incorporate what you have here and still the files aren't renamed.